# share, copy and delete in UIImagePickerController in SDK 3.0?

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to share copy and delete image using UIImagePickerController in SDK3.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UIImagePickerController` class and it's delegate protocol are for capturing images that you can use within your application, either by using the camera (if available) or the photo library.

You can't use the interface provided by the `UIImagePickerController` for anything other than what is stated above.

You can however, use it to pick the image you want. Once that it done, you can do anything with that image within your app. If you want to create a similar interface to the `UIImagePickerController`, you can. You can then implement the copy and share functionality from there. I don't think you can delete images from the user's photo library though, so that may not be possible.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply..ok fine..but is it possible for multiple selection of images..like selection of images in Photos app from the iPhone....

Comment: Multiple image selection isn't supported by the `UIImagePickerController` unfortunately. It can be used to pick one image or one video.

Comment: oh ok..thanks..is there any other way todo for multiple selection of images

Comment: Unfortunately not. The SDK only allows one image/video to be chosen from the library at a time. If you have images stored elsewhere (on the web, for example) then you can write your own picker that looks the same, but allows multiple selection of images. However, if the images are taken with the camera or exist in the users library, then it's limited to one at a time, sorry.

Comment: thats sad..i dont understand y so much of restrictions from apple..ok fine thanks for the replies..

Comment: I can see that you've asked 6 questions, and not chosen an answer for any of them. You should choose an answer that answers your question and mark it as the chosen answer, or else people will be much less inclined to answer your questions in the future.